# Scanner.nextLine() takes only half a line

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have files with data. It looks like this

Fragment below is only a part of the file (1. line of fragment is about 40 000. line in the file)

```
(...)
mh,majuro,Majuro,00,,7.1,171.3833333
mk,adzarlar,Adzarlar,79,,41.9780556,21.6494444
mk,adzemka,Adzemka,10,,41.8947222,20.9425
mk,adzibegovo,Adzibegovo,60,,41.7602778,21.9852778 
(...)
```

Then in Java I'm trying to do something with each line of file

```
    File file = new File("resources/file.txt");
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(file);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] array = line.split(",");

            (something with input)
        }
```

I have a problem with Scanner.nextLine() method. When I'm loading whole file, for a couple of lines, scanner is not fetching the whole line, e.g. (this is state of line variable before the error)

```
mk,adzemka,Adzemka,10
```

but when i create a new file with those 4 lines and then load newly created file, everything goes without problems. I have a bunch of another files like that (same structure, 250k lines) and they also go without problems. What could be wrong with this file?

Comment: It probably has a line break (\r or \n) that your editor is not showing you.

Comment: But why if I copy this line (and a few before and after it) scanner takes the whole line and not when it's from bigger file?

Comment: Maybe your editor removes this line break when copying and pasting. We can't say anything without seeing the file.

Comment: Unrelated *(maybe)*, but do not use `Scanner` for line reading. It is *extremely* slow. Use a `BufferedReader` instead. Or better yet, use an actual CSV parser, since you *are* reading [Comma-Separated Values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). E.g. [Apache Commons CSV™](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner's nextLine(), Only fetching partial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157689/scanners-nextline-only-fetching-partial)